# How can I add the mean of groups as a new group in a tidy data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have some time-series data in a tidy format, and I would like to calculate the mean for the x variable of the different trials and add this to the the dataframe as a new trial.

```
   frame trial  x     T
 * <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1 0.981 0    
 2     2     1 0.952 0.144
 3     3     1 0.963 0.289
.
.
.
71     1     2 0.988 0
72     2     2 0.997 0.144
73     3     2 0.996 0.289
.
.
.
```

I can do this by using `rbind(my.df, subset(my.df, trial == "1")` to create a new observation, and then exchange the values by `my.df$x = rowSums(trial_matrix)`

For that, first I'd need to put the x values of my trials into a trial-by-timepoint matrix.
It feels like there should be a more efficient way of doing this with `dplyr`, yet I only find examples of getting the mean in a group not for the whole vector across groups, e.g.

```
my.df %>%
     group_by(trial) %>%
     dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(x))
```

produces

```
  trial    Mean
  <chr> <dbl>
1     1  1.07
2     2  1.08
3     3  1.19
4     4  1.34
```

Comment: The expected output would be a set of new rows (equal to the number of observations / trial), where `frame` and `T` values are the same as for a single trial, but `x` values are the mean of all the trials' `x` vectors and the value of `trial` is "mean".
I'm not familiar with mini-Markdown so it might take a while to produce this in a nicely formatted way

Comment: I would like to create new rows, like adding a new trial, but with `x` values generated as the mean of all other `x` vectors of the individual trials

Comment: probably the simplest is just to add that new trial with `rbind()` and extract the `x` vector of individual trials into a matrix, then just replace the new trials' `x` with the `rowSums()` of that matrix. I guess this is a too specific thing to have a dplyr solution

Comment: v4k0l4t, can you provide both *input* and *intended output* in the form of something we can use? Best is often the output from `dput(...)`, and the sample of data need not be huge (better if it is not) but big enough for you to be able to manually augment with your intended additional rows (added manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate it and merge, for example if your data is such:

```
set.seed(111)
my.df = data.frame(
frame = sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),
trial = sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),
x = runif(100,min=1,max=100)
)
```

I suppose frame is the time point, and you need an average per timepoint, across all trials:

```
library(dplyr)
my.df %>% group_by(frame) %>% summarize(T=mean(x)) %>% right_join(my.df)

Joining, by = "frame"
# A tibble: 100 x 4
   frame     T trial     x
   <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1     2  51.5     3  2.70
 2     3  57.1     3 32.7 
 3     3  57.1     3 53.4 
 4     3  57.1     2 67.0 
 5     1  45.1     1 39.8 
 6     3  57.1     3 28.0 
 7     1  45.1     1 29.5 
 8     3  57.1     2 75.2 
 9     2  51.5     3 52.3 
10     1  45.1     1 74.0
```

Now for the same frame, you have similar values.